# Ampersands converted to '&amp;' when calling a URL from PHP

Tags: php, url

I have a problem when trying to make a call to a URL from a PHP script which will send a Signal message to my phone. The message I get is:

> PHP Warning:  `file_get_contents(https://signal.callmebot.com/signal/send.php?phone=+44xxxxxxxxx&amp;apikey=xxxxxx&amp;text=Lightning+strikes+in+last+hour%3A+1+%5BCheckweatherlogLightning%5D)`: failed to open stream: Connection timed out

When I copy the URL (from the PHP warning message) into the browser and run it there, I get the message 'Apikey parameter is missing'. Which suggests to me that the substitution of `'&amp;'` messes up the parsing at the other end. If I try the URL from the browser (correctly formed with `'&'` in the parameters) it works fine.

This is my code for the actual call:

```
$url='https://signal.callmebot.com/signal/send.php?phone='.$smsnumber.'&apikey='.$smsapikey.'&text='.urlencode($message);

$return=file_get_contents($url);
```

My question is, how do I ensure that the URL is sent as I build it, with `'&'` and not `'&amp;'`? Thanks.

Comment: `Which suggests to me that the substitution of '&amp;' messes up the parsing at the other end`...yes. but only in the HTML-encoded version you see on your web page. That isn't the URL which file_get_contents used.  The reason your request failed is due to the reason given in the message - "Connection timed out".

Comment: I would suggest changing to cURL instead of file_get_contents. It's actually meant for sending/receiving data from other sites.

Comment: Yeah, using cURL and the code from one of the other answers suggested (I guess I didn't hit the right search phrase to find that myself) has worked. Thanks